# find every occurrence of char codes 255,251,178 respectively. In a string or array

Tags: javascript

Using `indexOf('ÿ')// char for Unicode 255` for example, doesn't work. Probably because `indexOf()` needs the Unicode to be less than 127, maybe?.

Anyway, I have a big string array from an Ajax binary. I need to find every occurrence of a byte sequence, let's say the sequence is: 255,251,178. Each occurrence's location (loc of the 255 in the sequence) should then be pushed into an array to create this: `arr[0]=1st sequence occurrences location` `arr[1]=2nd sequence occurrences location` etc. The search through the string should be able to start at a specified offset. My problem is I can't even get `indexOf()` to detect the char for unicode 255.

Any help would be appreciated, greatly.

Pat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without evaluating the merit of your algorithm, you'll be better defining unicode chars like `'\u00FF'`

Second, indexOf will find any (Unicode) char you want, no such thing as "will not find less than 127".

Comment: Accepted this answer as the solution. Unicode char's should be referenced as stated above. which I did not know. Put in a loop, it works like a charm. Thanks, mdrg.

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected for me (using Node.js):

```
> var a = '\u00FF';
> console.log(a);
ÿ
> var string="hello, "+a+"there!";
> console.log(string);
hello, ÿthere!
> console.log(string.indexOf(a));
7
> console.log(string.indexOf("ÿ"));
7
>
```

On the other hand, you keep mentioning "bytes". Javascript strings are Unicode characters, typically stored in more than one byte each. And you say "Ajax binary" - what's that supposed to mean? Most/all Ajax results are going to be a text format, not binary. Javascript doesn't handle binary data very well.

Could you maybe post a little more detail about what you're trying to do?

Comment: Mark@: Bytes, is what I have in the binary data that I am working with. The `responseText` from the Ajax request comes down as text, but with the help of `overrideMimeType`.... and `ff[z] = scc(text.charCodeAt(z) & 255)`; I have a true binary data string. So in essence, it's bytes to me, although parsing with JavaScript, it is seen as Unicode. same difference right?, a value of 255 is a value of 255, Unicode or byte. So my end goal is to find every occurrence of byte/Unicode sequence ff,fb,b2 that resides in the string, and put the locations in an array as described in the question.

Comment: @cube : 255 is 0xFF as a byte, but the Unicode character \u00FF is a TWO BYTE sequence `0xC3 0xBF` when encoded in UTF-8 or a two byte sequence `0x00 0xFF` in UTF-16 (or it could be `0xFF 0x00` depending on the byte order mark) Trying to treat Unicode as a byte stream is difficult - you have to know what the encoding was and run it through a proper decoder.

Comment: Okay, but if you're pulling the bytes out of the response and masking them down to 8 bits already, then why are you using indexOf? I still feel like I'm missing something. Maybe if you add some code to your original question illustrating the issue, someone can point out where your problem is.

Comment: If you want to use indexOf() on the responseString, you need to search for the 16-bit sign-extended version of the character, so instead of searching for 255, 251, and 178, you'd be searching for 0xFFFF, 0xFFFB, and )xFFB2 (I think - it depends on how the browser handles those characters).

Comment: @Stephen and Mark: I used indexOf() because that is the string method (so far that I see) that returns the actual address of the  needles that I am looking for. Regexp is slower than indexOf(). So, I am simply trying to carry out a search for a pattern in the byte stream, and to have the script put all the addresses of the located patterns into an array.

Comment: @cube: In a test string `var text = "Hello ÿ World"` manipulated in the Firebug console, `text[6]` outputs *"ÿ"*, `text.charCodeAt(6)` outputs *255*, and `text.charCodeAt(6) & 255` also outputs *255*, and `text.indexOf('ÿ')` outputs *6*. But this doesn't take into account what your `scc(...)` method does, that is being passed the `charcode & 255` as shown in your first comment in this answer. Please show what `scc()` does.

Comment: @Stephen: var scc= String.fromCharCode;